# renewed certificate and app provisioning profile, but it still said provisioning profile expired

Tags: iphone

My certificate had expired, so I renewed the certificate and created the new provisioning profile with same app bundle id(app identifier).

I added the certificate file to 'keychain access' and added the provisioning profile to 'xcode'.

I could see the new provisioning profile in Organizer

[image]

but when I installed the ad hoc version to my ipod, it still reported provisioning profile expired
  :-(

[image]

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got an old copy of the profile on your device. Go to Settings and delete any old profiles.

Comment: I try again, but the result is same

Comment: I also test on my ipad (new purchased, has no old provisioning profile), it works

Comment: It looks like I can not fully remove the old profile from my device(ipod, os 3.1.3)

Comment: See also @Anomie's answer -- you may also need to remove old profiles from Xcode's Organizer window. If you don't, Xcode may re-install them even after you've removed them from the device.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the old profile from both the device and from the XCode organizer. Or, for good measure, delete all versions of the profile and then reinstall just the new one.